# Why am I getting an error in simple "get" using Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, scala, jpa

I have a simple class with JPA annotations:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "archive_operators")
class User {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "aop_user_id")
  @BeanProperty var userID: String = _

  @Column(name = "aop_pswd", nullable = false)
  @BeanProperty var password: String = _

  @Column(name = "aop_access", nullable = false)
  @BeanProperty var access: String = _
}
```

And I'm doing a simple get (`session` is an instance or `org.hibernate.Session`):

```
val result = session.get(clazz, id)
```

And getting an exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '.'.

There is a line in the log:

2014-03-21 08:58:30,201 DEBUG [pool-1-thread-9] o.h.SQL [SqlStatementLogger.java:109] select user0_.aop_user_id as aop_user1_0_0_, user0_.aop_access as aop_acce2_0_0_, user0_.aop_pswd as aop_pswd3_0_0_ from List().archive_operators user0_ where user0_.aop_user_id=?

The "from List()" part is very suspicious, but I have no idea where that's coming from. This get used to work, so obviously I changed something somewhere, but I'm at a loss as to what or how it is causing this problem.

Comment: If that is the only class that has this problem, try commenting out all fields (except ID) and then enable them back field by field to see what is the problem.

Comment: Ok, tried that. No difference. Looking more closely at the log, I saw an entry which might be a useful clue: 2014-03-21 10:04:22,448 DEBUG [ScalaTest-run-running-ContextTest] o.h.p.e.AbstractEntityPersister [AbstractEntityPersister.java:3681]  Version select: select aop_user_id from List().archive_operators where aop_user_id =?

Comment: So all entities that you have behave the same way?

Comment: Show us your persistence.xml It seems you have there a `List()` in the name of the database in your JDBC source.

Comment: @AndreiI - not using persistence.xml, I'm using JPA annotations. But to answer your other question - the app uses two databases, one Derby, one SQL Server. The Derby queries are all fine, the SQL Server queries all contain "List()", and are thus wrong. I'm using a new version of Hibernate, could be a bug there.

Comment: List() looks like a scala empty list collection toString result. Imho the bug could come from the "scala / last hibernate version" couple

Comment: @Gab - I think you're on to something there with the empty list/toString comment. It appears the part of my code that supposed to set hibernate.default_schema to the empty string is setting it "List()" instead.

Comment: :D fine that you got it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Imho it's a problem of sql dialect

Can you ensure you have something like that in hibernate configuration

```
<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
    [...]
   <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
    [...]
```

Comment: Good thought, but no. Also from the debug: 2014-03-21 08:58:27,545 DEBUG [ScalaTest-run-running-ContextTest] e.s.e.d.DBModule [DBModule.scala:288] [DBSessionFactory.loadProperties] Property: hibernate.dialect set to: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect

Comment: did you replace some java collection by a scala one somewhere ? or maybe override a toString() method ? If I were you i'll get hibernate source to debug the code which generate the sql.
Good question anyway, sorry for trivial suggestion :)